# cachebusting for all static resources in Turbogears 1.0b1

Tags: python, browser-cache, turbogears

Having a problem with stale `css` and `js` files being cached in the browser.

I am using the cache-buster technique of appending a query parameter with a datestamp
to static resource url's named explicitly in the main site template.

However I now need to use a similar technique (appending revision number instead of datestamp), but now for all `css` and `js` files including library files.

I am still learning TurboGears and have scoured the docs, but I can't see a simple
way to accomplish the append (for all static resources).  Any pointers?

This is a legacy Turbogears 1.0b1 application which may be upgraded to Django at some point.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A `file.js?v=1.1` type scenario would work and revise at various future points. Using the timestamp option is best used in dev/staging than production environments.

Comment: Good point Nickar.  My main challenge now is to understand how TG packages up js files and how the suffix can be most easily added.